# Is it possible to create self referencing custom element components in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting a circular reference error for something similar to the following and wanted to know if it's possible to get this working without duplicating code in one of my templates.  Here's the scenario:

component 1:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-table'
template: `
    <table>
        <custom-dropdown>
        </custom-dropdown>
    </table>
`
})

export class MyTableComponent {

}

@NgModule({
    imports: [CustomDropdownModule],
    declarations: [MyTableComponent],
    exports: [MyTableComponent]
})
export class MyTableModule
```

component 2:

```
@Component({
selector: 'custom-dropdown'
template: `
    <div>
        <my-table>
        </my-table>
    </div>
`
})

export class CustomDropdownComponent {

}

@NgModule({
    imports: [MyTableModule],
    declarations: [CustomDropdownComponent ],
    exports: [CustomDropdownComponent ]
})
export class CustomDropdownModule
```

Issue here is that both NgModules import each other.  I can solve this by duplicating some of the code from one of the component's templates into the other and thus eliminating the need for the circular reference but I would rather not do that if there is a way to make this work. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here or is there a way to get this working?

Comment: I think it's only going to work if you have them in the same module.

Comment: To me, this seems fundamentally wrong. 

MyTable displays CustomDropdown which displays MyTable which displays CustomDropdown which displays MyTable and so on and so forth. If this was displayed in the DOM it would be a never-ending chain of children like
`<my-table><custom-dropdown><my-table><custom-dropdown></custom-dropdown></my-table></custom-dropdown</my-table> with no end in sight.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: For context, the table has columns which contain a dropdown.  I'm creating a scenario where it's possible for that dropdown to contain a table (to show more than one column of data).  I wanted to reuse my existing table component to accomplish this so I don't end up copying some of the table code into the drop down. But yes you are right, if you really went out of the way you could feasible cause an endless loop of table dropdowns.  And I did consider doing it once I got this working :)

Comment: @YannickBeauchamp-H that was the answer I was looking for, the new dropdown component just had a template parse error in it so I thought I was doing something wrong.